# Maximal solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

Let $K\subset X$ be a compact set and let $x_0\in K$. Suppose that the maximal solution $x(t)$

Comment: Are the some conditions on the differential equation that guarantee existence?

Comment: Then you know that $T^+$ is open (in $[0, \infty)$) and since $x$ is continuous, you have $x^{-1}(K)$ is closed. Now use connectedness of $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is locally Lipschitz, then a local solution exists, hence $T^+$ is open
(in $[0, \infty)$). Furthermore, $x$ is continuous.

Since $K$ is compact, it is closed, hence $T^+ = x^{-1}(K)$ is closed.

Consequently $T^+ \subset [0, \infty)$ is both open and closed. Since $0 \in T^+$, $T^+$ is not empty. Since $[0,\infty)$ is connected, we must have
$T^+ = [0,\infty)$.

**Note**: A set is connected **iff** the only subsets that are both open and closed are the empty set or the set itself.

Comment: Glad to be able to help!